# Affiliate scheme that kicks back a % of sales to the affiliate using AppsFlyer

Tags: appsflyer

How can I guide my dev team to build this?

I would like to pay affiliates a % of Rental Fees from renters who rent vehicles on the app.  App is a vehicle marketplace not unlike Turo. Dev is suggesting pay for app downloads instead of rental fees, but this seems like a bad idea that can be easily gamed & very expensive.

Is there a way to do this with AppsFlyer?  Like assign each renter/user an ID that is attributed to the affiliate, and any subsequent rental calcs the % commission and passes that info back for payouts.

What's a rough framework for accomplishing this?